# How do I adjust the y axis without messing up the x axis in r for multiple histograms?

Tags: r, plot, histogram, data-visualization, density-plot

Hi I am trying to put 7 histograms with different Y axis scales on the same plot in r.  If I don't scale the images the X axis looks fine if I scale them it screws everything up.  Here is what I am doing:
[Link to my code](http://justpaste.it/g58)

I think that the problem is that I am just calling par(new=T), and that maybe there is a better way to get all of the histograms on the same x scale.
How do I adjust the y axis so that all of the histograms are on the same scale but also make sure that the scale on the x axis is the same as well?  Thanks

[image: Histograms of pixel intensity data without scaling]

[image: Histograms of pixel intensity data without scaling]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to force the same x-scale with `xlim = c(n, p)` where `n` and `p` are the minimum and maximum values of your choosing.

excerpted from `?xlim`

```
Usage:

 plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = "", asp = NA, ...)

Arguments:

xlim, ylim: numeric vectors of length 2, giving the x and y coordinates
      ranges.
```